# Suppressing GPG signing for Maven-based continuous integration builds (Travis CI)

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, gnupg, travis-ci

I'm using [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to provide continuous integration builds for a few Java open source projects I'm working on.

Normally this works smoothly, but I have a problem when the POM specifies GPG signing, e.g.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>sign-artifacts</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>sign</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This causes the Travis build to fail - apparently because it does not have a passphrase available while running `mvn install`. See [this build](https://travis-ci.org/nuroko/nurokore/jobs/4683227) for an example.

What is the best way to configure Maven and/or Travis to skip GPG signing for CI test builds, but still perform GPG signing when I do a proper release build?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to create a profile & make sure you run that only when you do the release build.

Remove the current plugin, and add it in a profile like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then when you actually need to do a release, add the property to your mvn command:

```
mvn -DperformRelease=true ...
```

Comment: Assuming you're using the release plugin: instead of using an activation via the flag you could just add that profile to the `releaseProfiles` plugin setting.

Comment: Alternatively you can make the activation property name `${env.TRAVIS}` with a value of `true`. This is because Travis-CI containers are spun-up with various built-in environmental variables (including for example `TRAVIS=true` and `CI=true`) and Maven can detect them via the maven syntax for environmental variables `${env.<variable>}`. This approach has the benefit of not requiring you to add a system property to every Maven command, but still allowing you to mock activation of the profile and have automatic activation of the profile during the CI build.

Answer (score 107):

Disable GPG signing by adding the following line to your `.travis.yml` file:

```
install: mvn install -DskipTests -Dgpg.skip
```

Example: https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: I was getting weird gpg errors with Maven and msysgit. Your answer helped me. Thanks

Comment: Note that adding `skipTests` for a CI build may not be the best idea.

Comment: In general you're right, but not here ;-) See: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/

Comment: Am trying to use -Dgpg.skip=true in my maven release build under jenkins. It seems to have no effect . Any ideas?

Comment: @StefanBirkner what are you mean?

Comment: The `install` script is only a preparation for executing the build command. The build command will not skip the tests. For more details please read the documentation of Travis CI. It provides a good explanation that I would not like to repeat.

Comment: In my case it works only when quoted `-D"gpg.skip=true"`

Answer (score 13):

I found a slightly simpler way to do it with the profile as described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14869692/1127485).  Instead of using a new property value, you can use the *gpg.passphrase* property which will need to be provided anyway when doing signing.  The modified property section is as follows:

```
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>gpg.passphrase</name>
    </property>
</activation>
```

Notice, that no value is required since you want this profile to activate if any value is set for that property.

The corresponding command line then looks like this:

```
mvn <command> -Dgpg.passphrase=myverysupersecretpassphrase
```

You can test this out by running it the following two ways:

```
mvn install
```

No signed artifacts get generated, and:

```
mvn install -Dgpg.passphrase=myverysupersecretpassphrase
```

Signed artifacts get created.

To do the actual signed release of the artifacts do the following:

```
mvn release:perform -Darguments=-Dgpg.passphrase=myverysupersecretpassphrase
```

The indirection is needed for the release action because it doesn't propagate the command line arguments directly to the spawned process (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-gpg-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against this approach if you're using a shell that saves command history, as you probably don't want your GPG passphrase floating around in your `~/.bash_history` file or whatever.

(FYI: The only shell I know of these days that _doesn't_ save history is a regular DOS command prompt.)