# Maven ignore gpg plugin and passphrase during install phase not working due to bad settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I tried to push the gpg plugin to settings.xml as per the post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14869692/596720. So that I don't have to use passphrase when doing an install. However I get the exception that the `build` element within profile is invalid content. On checking the schema that turns out to be true. So how do I get gpg plugin to stop executing during install?